How do jetstream migrate between nodes?
Say I have deployed a NATS cluster with 5 nodes using Helm, and I have a stream with no replication. Now I modify the values so that the config.cluster.replicas become 3. There is possibility that the stream were stored on the stepped down nodes such that the stream becomes unreachable. Should I manually apply the replication before rescaling?
